# How to translate properly 还是 and 算了 in this sentence?

Tags: translation, word, phrase

> 唉，以前挖门打洞，清苦死了，还是城市好，干脆留在这儿享福算了.

This is a sentence said by a village mouse which came to the city and realised how wonderful the life in the city is.

还是城市好 - how to translate 还是 here? I believe the whole phrase means "On the other hand, the city is good"?

享福算了 - I THINK I should understand it as 享 (enjoy) + 福 (happiness) + 算了. What's the meaning of 算了 here and, consequently, what's the meaning of 享福算了? Does it mean "enjoying happiness taken for granted" or "forget about enjoying happiness" in the imperative form, or "enjoy happiness and forget the rest" in the imperative form, or something else?

Edit:
In fact, I don't understand how the speaker could get away with not putting 很 in 城市好. Please, help me understand this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

还是 denotes this sense defined in dictionaries:

> 表示对某一事实的强调 (denotes an emphasis on a certain fact)

> E. g.  这种事我还是第一次遇到。

So, 还是城市好 means something along the line of *in view of all the circumstances (or after all), the city is better (to live)*, implying that after some comparison he feels the city is better to live.

算了 means *leave/make it that way*.  享福算了 means *just to enjoy happiness from life*.

As for this part:

> Edit: In fact, I don't understand how the speaker could get away with not putting 很 in 城市好.

the sentence 还是城市好 sets up a comparison here (comparing to countryside).  Well, 城市很好 is just to express *city life is quite good* and it doesn't implies any comparison.  One may say: 城市很好, 但乡下也很好。and 和乡下比，还是城市好。

Answer (score 2):

In these contexts: 还是 means 'still (after all)' in comparison to a previously mentioned or implied known object; 算了 means 'just (simply)'

**还是**城市好 = (after all) the city **is still** better

享福**算了** = **just** (simply) enjoy life

More example:

**还是**工作重要 = work **is still** more important (after all)

干脆辞职**算了** = simply **just** resign

Example of 还是 in another context (followed by a verb instead of a noun):

(**还是**)放弃(**算了**) - (**better off**) (**just**) give up